# ASP.Net Core MVC IdentityFrameWork Not Working

Tags: authentication, identity

I have an ASP.Net Core MVC application which uses IdentityFrameworkCore for the login which seems to work fine but I can access other web pages without login in by typing the URL in.

Also it is loading my _Layout page with my login page showing menu items.

Can someone please help on how I call my login page without _Layout and how do I prevent users from bypassing the login.

Many Thanks,

Comment: have you decorated the controllers with the `[Authorize]` attribute?

Comment: Perfect, that works. Do you know how I call my login page without my _layout. I found an article saying set Layout=null which works but I lose my css format on my login page. Thanks very much.

Comment: If I recall correctly, `_layout` references an identity method which triggers the login. If you call any secured method, and you haven't logged in, it should show the login page

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The login page now loads if I try and access via URL without being login but it still loads _Layout.

Comment: It's a while since I've done ASP.Net MVC but you must have a reference to _Layout somewhere